# What are these x and y scaling options for a tikzpicture for?

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling

I've googled myself silly already, but I still can't really pinpoint it enough to reassure myself what exactly those options do:

What does `x=0.25cm` in the MWE stand for? Does it stand for: "every `cm` measure you'll give in this `tikzpicture`-environment will be scaled, in this specific case by the factor `0.25`"? So what about measures given in `pt` or other units?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
lmodern,
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{
tikz
}



\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.25cm,font=\sffamily\small]
%
\draw[style=help lines,step=0.5cm] (0,0) grid (16,4);
%
\draw[->,thick] (-0.1,0) -- (6.5,0) node[anchor=west]{x};
\draw[->,thick] (0,-0.1) -- (0,6.5) node[anchor=south]{y};
%
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,6} \draw [thick](\x cm,-2pt) -- (\x cm,2pt) node[anchor=north,yshift=-2pt]{\x};
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,6} \draw [thick](-2pt,\y) -- (2pt,\y) node[anchor=east,xshift=-2pt] {\y};
%
\begin{scope}[color=black]
\filldraw (1,1) circle (0.08cm) node (A) {} node[anchor=north,fill=white,yshift=-0.1cm] {A};
\filldraw (6,6) circle (0.08cm) node (B) {} node[anchor=west,fill=white,xshift=5pt] {B};
\end{scope}
\draw[very thick] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Any relative measure (which is not followed by a unit) will use the  globally specified unit.

Comment: I am quite sure I used tikz before without specifying anything globally and `cm` was used anyhow. Also, the scaling does not apply to the tikz on the x-axis and its labels. Thus I don't think that was all there is to it.

Comment: By default, all units (horizontal, vertical, radial) are `1cm`.

Comment: But if you explicitly specify the unit, such as `\draw (1pt,3cm) circle (3km)` then the global specified unit will be ignored.

Comment: Wow. Finally. Thank you. :) So what exactly happens if I just use `x=0.25`? I can't figure out the rule there, it certainly does not scale the measures in `cm` by a quarter, more like an eightth... maybe? You could post your comment as a reply, btw.

Comment: `x=.25` equals to `x=.25pt`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `x=<value>` is the same as `x=<value>pt`.
- By default, global units for horizontal, vertical, and radial are `1cm`.
- Globally specified unit only affects measures without explicitly specified unit. For example, `x=2cm` will affect the abscissa in `(2,...)` but not in `(2pt,...)`.
- Use relative measures for things that potentially need scaling. The best candidate for this is the length of a rectangle (for example).
- Use absolute measures for things that do not need scaling. The best candidate for this is the line width (for example).

---

*Added by Andrew Stacey*: A picture (with code) paints 1024 words:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122428/86}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[red] (0,-.2cm) -- (5cm,-.2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.25cm]
\draw (0,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[red] (0,-.2cm) -- (5cm,-.2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.25pt]
\draw (0,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[red] (0,-.2cm) -- (5cm,-.2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(0.25,0)}]
\draw (0,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[red] (0,-.2cm) -- (5cm,-.2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.25]
\draw (0,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[red] (0,-.2cm) -- (5cm,-.2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Different values for <code>x=</code>]

Comment: Hope the edit's okay - didn't seem worth posting as a separate answer.

Comment: In PSTricks, `xunit=1` is the same as `xunit=1cm` (not `xunit=1pt`).

Comment: I was expecting `x=1` to be `x=1cm` in TikZ as well so I did the above experiment to check your statement in the comments.  Note that `x={(1,0)}` is the same as `x=1cm` (assuming that `x` wasn't set to anything else beforehand).

Comment: It is `1pt`, not `1bp`.  The key `x=1` gets processed as `\pgfpoint{1}{0pt}` and this assumes `pt` for unitless quantities.  You can test this with `\makeatletter\pgfpoint{1}{0pt}\showthe\pgf@x\makeatother`, and replacing `1` by `1pt` and `1bp` and comparing the results.